# Python removing the first line in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a for loop this this in python:

```
for line in res.split('\n'):
   po=line.split()
   print(po)
```

The output is:

> ip prefix-list Google permit 219.103.51.0/24
>
> ip prefix-list Google permit 219.109.128.0/19
>
> ip prefix-list Google permit 220.247.184.0/21
>
> ip prefix-list Google permit 223.27.116.0/22
>
> ip prefix-list Google permit 223.27.116.0/24

how can i remove the first line from the loop so i can do the next command?

```
po2='{} {} {} {} {}'.format(po[0],po[1],po[2],po[3],po[4])
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, but if you want to skip the first line, maybe you're looking for `for line in res.split('\n')[1:]:`?

Comment: you have saved me hours!!!

Comment: We can't help you solve that problem without a [mcve]. But that's a different problem, so you should post a new question.

Comment: Don't do that. You can't change your question, especially after you've already received an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to start iterating from the second element. Eg, instead of

```
for line in res.split('\n')
```

write

```
for line in res.split('\n')[1:]
```

Look up python's *slicing* of lists/iterables.